# Why Do we use Session() state instead of global variables in ASP.NET? what is the point?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, session-state

Why Do we use Session() state object in ASP.NET to store and retrieve data throughout the session of any user? Why not use global variables instead of session()....And similarly View() state to store and access data anywhere inside a page...Why this functionality exists while we can simply store the data in a Variable and access it wherever needed? Please Clarify

Comment: Because HTTP is stateless. Every new request is just that - a _new request_. Session variables, Application variables, Cache - these are ways of giving some kind of 'state' to a, by nature, stateless architecture.

Comment: Its time you learned about stateless nature of asp.net :) . [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.140).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers I came across is that during the occurrence of Page PostBack there may be a chance that the variables might become empty and so the data in the variables will be lost. Hence why we use states for accessing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use value of session anywhere in your application and global variables can be use on a single page. Whenever page will be refreshed value of global variables becomes empty but session value will be remain as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 concepts Session, View State and Global objects does the same job of saving and accessing the values.

The main difference comes in stating the scope of this value assigned to the variable. Below definition will explain you the same.

1> Global variable: The scope of global variable (declared either through a singleton pattern or application state) has a application scope. i.e; the value assigned to this variable will be accessible in all the sessions and will be same at a point of time of all sessions and in all pages. These value are stored in  the .NET Framework common language runtime and is same across application. 
For eg: A connection string, database name etc.

2> Sessions State: The value assigned to a session state object will have a scope only for that session (until you perform a session.abondon). 
For eg: when you login to a website the website might store your login Id in a session variable. This session variable will be accessible in all the pages until you log out.

3> View state: The scope of view state is the page and subsequent postbacks. Once you navigate to a different page the values are gone. This is mainly used to store a calculated values that can used after the post back. Also, ASP.net internally uses viewstate to populate the control values after postback.
View state is a page level state management.